# Calculate gas-station probabilities

Tags: probability

I would like to calculate probabilities for the next exercise:

**Knowing the average amount of cars that drive per minute into a gas-station is 3.**

** How can I calculate the probability of arriving at least 12 cars into the station in a period of 5 minutes?

** And the probability of a car arriving before two minutes go by?

Thank you all very much in advance.

Comment: Don't you need some further assumption about distribution of arrivals? such as whether this is a Poisson process, or an exponential distribution, or uniform, or....

Comment: There was no initial assumption, just the average. I think an exponential Poisson distribution should be used but I can not figure out the exercise. Thanks.

Comment: I think exponential distribution and Poisson distribution are two different things.

Comment: A very similar problem is #2 at http://www.pat-rossi.com/MTH4451/Test2/Spring2009/spsol_09a.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use a Poisson model.  So if $X$ is the number of cars in randomly chosen $1$ minute interval, then $X$ is assumed to have Poisson distribution with parameter $3$.

Thus by general theory, the number $Y$ of cars in a $5$ minute interval has Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda=15$. thus the probability of fewer than $12$ cars in a $5$ minute interval   is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{11}e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}.\tag{$1$}$$
This is a somewhat unpleasant calculation. Maybe compute from $k=11$ **down.** After a while, the terms you are adding become negligible. The probability of at least $12$ cars is $1$ minus the probability computed in $(1)$.

The number $Z$ of cars in a $2$ minute interval has Poisson distribution with parameter $6$. We want the probability of at least one car, which is $1$ minus the probability of no cars. The probability of no cars is $e^{-6}$.  Alternately, for the no cars problem one can use the relationship between the Poisson and the exponential.